# Changing an image through CSS

Tags: html, css, image, css-selectors

I want to replace the main "hero" background I have on one of my pages. Since I am using Wordpress, I am forced to use custom CSS (I cannot edit HTML).

I have tried targeting the div where the current photo is contained using class selectors as shown below:

```
.header .custom-mobile-image {

    background-image: url(https://thenovelcolumn.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/The-10X-Rule-Image-2-e1555476700855.jpg);


}
```

Here is the HTML code i am trying to target:

```
<div class="header custom-mobile-image" style="background-image: url("https://thenovelcolumn.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/education-books.jpg"); background-color: rgb(106, 115, 218); padding-top: 74.5938px;">
```

The link to the page itself: http://thenovelcolumn.com/the-10x-rule

The target photo is the first one on the page with three opened books in the center.

I expected my CSS code to change this photo to whatever the link specifies it to, but the photo remains unchanged.

Comment: You should escape the double quotes inside your style attribute or replace them with single quotes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because styles from "style" attribute have bigger specificity than any styles you might add with classes and even id's: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

So in this case only way is to use !important:

```
.header.custom-mobile-image {
    background-image: url(https://thenovelcolumn.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/The-10X-Rule-Image-2-e1555476700855.jpg) !important;
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

Your selector should be `.header.custom-mobile-image` (i.e no space between the two classes - they both are assigned to the same element, the space would mean a parent / child relation)

And you should add `!important` in that rule to override the more specific `style` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

here we go:

```
.header.custom-mobile-image {

background-image: url("https://thenovelcolumn.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/The-10X- 
Rule-Image-2-e1555476700855.jpg") !important;


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Writing inline css (style="some:css;") is not the best idea. It will allways neglect styles from your .css file. 
As someone already mentioned it's about specificity.
Weakest are type selectors (html tags and pseudo elements), then goes classes, then id's

if you have inline css, it will apply styles over .css file. Only thing stronger than inline css is using !important